# Is there a way in Selenium with Python to get the text of desktop notifications that have been sent from web-driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, push-notification

I tried a lot to find a way to test the push notifications sent from the web-driver. But I couldn't find any. I need to test the data and the message text of the notifications. Also, I add an image.
[Notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoJNv.png)

I tried a lot and did many types of research but there are no results on the internet.